# Is this theorem about Integration by Substitution correct?

Tags: real-analysis

The theorem of integration by substitution of my course is

> Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ an integrable function on $[a,b]$ and $\varphi :[c,d]\longrightarrow  \mathbb R$ continuous such that its derivative is continuous and $\varphi([c,d])\supset [a,b]$. Let $\alpha,\beta\in [c,d]$ such that $\varphi(\alpha)=a$ and $\varphi(\beta)=b$ ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ exists because $\varphi([c,d])\supset [a,b]$).
>   Therefore $$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_\alpha^\beta f(\varphi(y))\varphi'(y)\mathrm dy.$$

But something looks strange to me (in particular the fact that $\varphi([c,d])\supset [a,b]$ ... because if $\varphi([c,d])\neq [a,b]$ then $f(\varphi(x))$ is not defined, no?). So is it correct ?

Comment: It looks to have a problem. Indeed, if $y\in[\alpha,\beta]$ we don't necessarily have $\varphi(y)\in [\varphi(\alpha),\varphi(\beta)]$.

Comment: The one condition should be $\varphi([c,d])\subset[a,b]$.

Comment: Actually, I would say $\varphi([c,d])=[a,b]$.

Comment: @idm:   You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are also choosing $\alpha, \beta$ so that your range matches up. You can just choose them such that $|\alpha-\beta|$ is minimal. Then, your problem disappears.